# Should I always use wildcards as generic types for function arguments or only pass instances of one generic type?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Consider the following invalid Java code:

```
class Example {
    private static class Base {}
    private static class Child extends Base{
        public void do(){}
    }

    public void foo(List<Base>) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Child> list = new ArrayList<>();
        fillListInPlaceWithChildren(list);

        foo(list); //compile error, List<Child> does not extend List<Base>

        list.stream().forEach(Child::do);
    }
}
```

This does not compile because `List<Child>` is not a subclass of `List<Base>` and thus cannot be passed to the foo function. To solve this kind of problems I have, as far as I know, 2 options:

1. let foo accept `List<? extends Base>`:

   ```
   class Example {
       private static class Base {}
       private static class Child extends Base{
           public void do(){}
       }

       public void foo(List<? extends Base>) {}

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           List<Child> list = new ArrayList<>();
           fillListInPlaceWithChildren(list);

           foo(list); 
           list.stream().forEach(Child::do);
       }
   }
   ```
2. let `list` be a `List<Base>` and cast elements to instances of `Child` when needed

   ```
   class Example {
       private static class Base {}
       private static class Child extends Base{
           public void do(){}
       }

       public void foo(List<Base>) {}

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           List<Base> list = new ArrayList<>();
           fillListInPlaceWithChildren(list);

           foo(list); 
           list.stream().forEach((item) -> ((Child)item).do());
       }
   }
   ```

Which option is considered best practice and why? Or do they both have different use cases?

Comment: If foo takes in a List of base objects, why are you trying to treat it's the elements as Child? If you decide to pass it with `<? extends Base>` then you should only call methods which are in Base.

Comment: To you need the object in the `List` to behave like a `Base` object or a `Child` object?

Comment: As you can see in the examples it only requires the objects to behave like `Base` objects (otherwise the original `List<Base>` signature wouldn't make sense anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass `List<Child>` to a method requiring a `List<Base>` because it may cause some problems. What would happen in this case if you pass in a `List<Child>`?

```
void foo(List<Base> list) {
    list.add(new Base());
}
```

If you do not rely in the list holding only instances of `Base`. Using `List<? extends Base>` is safer than adding typecasts in your code, also it causes less surprises to who is reading the code.

Comment: You can't pass `List<Child>` when the method requires `List<Base>` because `List<Child>` does not extend `List<Base>` thus that kind of code does not even compile.

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to explain "why" the compiler can't accept that code. Some people may think that it's a shortcoming or a "failure" of the Java language.

Answer (score 1):

I always recomend to use higher level of abstraction. If you can use `List<Base> list` instead of `List<Child>` list, use it!.

But in this case is `foo` whom set its contract. Should foo accept all list inhered from `List<? extend Base>` or it only make sense to accept `List<Child>` ?

In the question is the answer.

Comment: I agree, the question is what does foo expect, Base and it's sub-classes (option #2) or sub-classes of Base (option #1). You 1st need to decide. Will you have instances of Base and are they acceptable? If not, I often mark these classes as abstract for clarity

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question: it is not `List<Child>` vs `List<Base>`, but `List<? extends Base>` vs `List<Base>`.